# Submitting data to google sheet with multiple tab sheets

Tags: ajax, google-sheets, tabs

I'm referencing this article "[How to Submit an HTML Form to Google Sheets…without Google Forms](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175)", it worked perfectly for me for only a Google Sheet with one tab.

Need help how to dynamically select what sheet tab the data should be written in the case the google sheet has multiple tabs. I'm using Ajax to submit google sheet btw.
Here's the call by the Ajax:

```
var $form = $('form#test-form'),
url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/MyScript/exec'

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(
    // do something
  );
})
```

The code on google sheet web app

```
function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

//  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
        var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

function handleResponse(e) {
  // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
  // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
  // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

If there is a way to change the variable SHEET_NAME dynamically then I think it will be good. Thanks

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show any code, or how you've tried to modify your code (and the resulting errors/issues your modifications resulted in?) If something didn't work, still share that you tried it (and why it didn't meet your requirements/qualifications for "working").

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried to keep my question short and direct that's why I link the article containing all codes... I implemented the codes as it is and I said that it worked for me, so I don't see the logic copying all codes here since my question is direct and concise.

Comment: You can certainly include the relevant minimal snippet of code that illustrates the issue you have and the related code that you have attempted to modify. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Pass the sheet name as a field in your form data? make sure you handle the case where that sheet name doesn't exist.